# Optimized way to add missing dates to Pandas Dataframe fast

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, optimization

Let's say I have the following dataframe that I want to backfill the missing dates from range '2023-11-09'  to '2023-11-14' for the 2 different stores. I have used the solution from the link
[Pandas fill missing dates and values simultaneously for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68500837/pandas-fill-missing-dates-and-values-simultaneously-for-each-group)

[DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZHVf.png)

```
dates = mydf.groupby(['STORE','ADDRESS'])['DATE'].nunique()

# Create MultiIndex with separate Date ranges per Group
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    dates.apply(
        lambda x: pd.date_range('2023-11-09', '2023-11-14', freq='D'), axis=1
    ).explode().reset_index(name='DATE')[['DATE', 'STORE', 'ADDRESS']]
)

# Reindex
mydf = (
    mydf.set_index(['DATE', 'STORE', 'ADDRESS'])
        .reindex(midx, fill_value=0)
        .reset_index()
)
```

I also tried the following codes:

```
def filling_missing_dates(df):
    import pandas as pd
    df['DATE']= pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
    group = df.groupby(['STORE','ADDRESS']).nunique()
    a = [pd.date_range('2023-11-09', '2023-11-14', freq='D')]
    b = []
    b.extend(a * len(group.index))
    ser = pd.Series(b,index=group.index)
    midx = 
    pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(ser.explode().reset_index(name='DATE'). 
    [['DATE', 'STORE', 'ADDRESS']])
    df = (df.set_index(['DATE', 'STORE', 
    'ADDRESS']).reindex(midx,fill_value=0).reset_index())
    return(df)
```

However, there was no major improvement in time for large datasets.

Using pivot table, I am able to do this in about 2 seconds.

However, I am trying to find a solution that optimizes the creation of multiindex. The lambda part operates row by row. As such, when the dataset is very large(millions of records), the operation is very slow. This part of the function consumes the most time. What's the way to optimize this and make it go faster for large datasets?

Comment: Have you tried the other solutions from that question? Some look like they are probably faster.

Comment: @Nick Do you mean the answer proposed by mozway from that question?

Comment: Well definitely @mozway answers are usually amongst the best

Comment: Please [edit] your question (click the `Edit` link under your question) to add additional information, don't put it in the comments.

Comment: @Nick - I added the additional information

Comment: There's some better looking answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978196/pandas-filling-missing-dates-and-values-within-group)